# do not allow to drag when input is in use or clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I do not want the div to be dragged when I am in input.

For example: when I have some text inside input and I try to highlight it, it does not highlight it; rather it drags the div

https://jsfiddle.net/213r38rL/

```html
<div id="select1" draggable="true" ondragstart="start(event)" ondragend="end(event)">
  SELECT
  <input type="text" name="select" id="selectinput">

</div>
```

Comment: Where are start and end defined? Can you edit the snippet I made to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `draggable=false` in the `focus` and `focusout` events:

```html
<div id="select1" draggable="true" ondragstart="start(event)" ondragend="end(event)">
  SELECT
  <input onfocus="document.getElementById('select1').draggable=false;" onfocusout="document.getElementById('select1').draggable=true;" type="text" name="select" id="selectinput">

</div>
```